# Problem in compiling LocalSolr

Tags: solr, localsolr

I am trying to install LocalSolr following the instruction here:

http://www.gissearch.com/node/16

Unfortunately things are not working well.

In the document, it says:

> To install these into solr simply copy the following jars to solr's lib directory.
>   located in apache-solr-1.*/example/solr/lib

I have noticed that I don't have a folder called "lib" under example/solr, so I built it myself and copied all the mentioned files to it.

And I went to the next step which was altering solrconfig.xml and schema.xml as instructed in here: http://www.gissearch.com/localsolr

and restarted my ApacheSolr, but got the following error:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'com.pjaol.search.solr.component.LocalSolrQueryComponent'

I can't figure out how to fix this problem so I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr includes official spatial search functionality as of version 3. Based on my experience running [Websolr](http://websolr.com/), I recommend you upgrade to Solr 3.3 rather than wrestle with LocalSolr.